# Can't create an OAuth client ID on Google Cloud Platform API Credentials

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to create an OAuth client ID on Google Cloud Platform but am having a major UI issue that is preventing me from creating it.

[image: Here is a GIF of the issue]

When I try to click on any button on the menu, I simply click the element behind the button. I have tried everything I can think of to fix this, including clearing cookies, reloading browser and even trying to click on the link through JavaScript, which bought me to an empty page. I am lost and any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: It's difficult to diagnose browser app issues like this because (a) the same experience works for others; (b) we've no idea what OS, browser, version, other installed apps that you have. Try a different browser on the same machine. Try another machine. Depending on your comfort level, you can check the browser's developer tools to see whether the console is reporting errors and/or whether there are issues retrieving resources.

Comment: @DazWilkin I should have tried a diffrent browser before posting. Works fine through Edge. Thank you!

Comment: So this (strongly) suggests that there's something awry with the original browser, possibly a plugin that's causing the untoward behavior.

Comment: Open the browser debugger (Inspect) and review the errors on the Console and Network tab.